# How can I remove internal noises of gear completely in this image

Tags: python, opencv

[image: gear image][gear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjNg0.jpg)

I want generalize method so that any type of noises inside the gear can be remove. I am using OpenCV with python
I have already try with lots filter and noise removing methods but I am not getting proper output. here is my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
from imutils import perspective
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
img1 = cv2.imread("5cam.png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
rows, cols = img.shape
dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(img, 15, 10, 7, 21)
gaussian_blurred_images = cv2.GaussianBlur(dst, (9, 9), 0)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gaussian_blurred_images, 200, 255,     cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
kernel = np.ones((7, 7), np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel)
canny = cv2.Canny(dilation, 200, 255)
contours = cv2.findContours(canny, mode=cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,  method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]
areas1 = []
for ctr in contours:
 areas = cv2.contourArea(ctr)
 areas1.append(areas)
 amax = max(areas1)
 max_contour = [contours[areas1.index(amax)]]
 cv2.drawContours(img1, max_contour, -1, (0, 255, 255), 2)
 cv2.imshow("g", dst)
 cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
 cv2.imshow("c", canny)
 cv2.imshow("img", img1)
 cv2.waitKey(0)
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I believe you wanted to attach an image but your post's text got corrupted?

Comment: for image click on above link

Comment: Could you also post the image you are getting as a result of your code?

Answer (score 0):

first you'll need to improve the lighting and scene.

- it needs to be more diffuse and not straight on, to prevent reflection on the gear. place lights to the side all around. don't use the camera's built in flash. use/build a "softbox" which is a white sheet of paper or fabric that diffuses the light before it hits the object (either translucent or used like a "mirror").
- it needs to be more uniform. your picture shows a "vignette", darkening near the picture's outside. the previous step will probably fix that.
- be careful about smudges, dirt on the background
- move the camera further away and use zoom if possible. that will improve the overall sharpness of the picture (more depth of focus) and reduce lens distortion (if you care about that).

then you'll need a different approach. I would suggest trying segmentation based on hue and saturation (select the uniformly blue background).

- use `cv.cvtColor` to transform the image into the HSV color space
- then use numpy indexing/masking (or `cv.inRange`) to select a small range of hue (somewhere around green-blue, which is probably a hue of around 180 degrees, or 90 in cvtColor's CV_8U hue values) and saturations (medium to full). for example: `mask = ((hsv_img >= (90, 170, 0)) & (hsv_img <= (100, 255, 255))).all(axis=2)`

that approach, on the unimproved lighting, gets me this far. on better lighting it should be even better.

[image]

Comment: can you please tell me how to find its inner and outer diameter using open CV and python

Comment: assuming this image here, I'd apply some morphological operation to remove the noise somewhat, then use `findContours` and `fitEllipse` to the outer contour to get a bounding circle. tutorial exist on various blogs and in OpenCV docs: https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html